# A few jQuery questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

First of all,  [here is the site I am working on](http://ha-test.pcc.dev.richterseven.com/index2.html).

I am trying to get a modal window to pop-up when elements in the Flash are clicked on. Which at this point I have about 90% working when you click on the warrior image. Below is a list of issues I am still trying to solve that I hope you can help me with...

- The modal background doesn't fill up
  the whole page like it should.
- I cannot get the close button to work
- I need to set the vidname variable in
  both the Flash and Java to load in a
  dynamic HTML file. Depending on which
  image is clicked on. My naming
  convention will probably be something
  like vid-1.html, vid-2.html, etc.

If you need to look at the .js file you can view it at /cmsjs/jquery.ha.js

Below is the ActionScript I currently have...

var vidname = "modal.html";

peeps.vid1.onRelease = function() {

getURL('javascript:loadVid(\'' + vidname + '\');');

};

Answer (score 0):

Well I have one for you.

Your current close code is

```
$('#modalBG, #modalClose').click(function(){
  closeModal();
});
```

If you click the background after a video loads you'll see that the modal does close. The reason your close button does not work is because `#modalClose` does not exist in the DOM when you are binding to the click function.

You need to either rebind the modalClose element when you modify the DOM or use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live). If you use live you just need to change your click code to this:

```
$('#modalBG, #modalClose').live("click", (function(){
  closeModal();
});
```